# Summation notation in Haskell

Tags: math, haskell, recursion, sum

On the Wikipedia page about [summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) it says that the equivalent operation in Haskell is to use *foldl*. My question is: Is there any reason why it says to use this instead of *sum*? Is one more 'purist' than the other, or is there no real difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`foldl` is a general [tail-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) reduce function. Recursion is the usual way of thinking about manipulating lists of items in a functional programming languages, and provides an alternative to loop iteration that is often much more elegant. In the case of a reduce function like `fold`, the tail-recursive implementation [is very efficient](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2006/12/tail_recursion_iteration_in_ha_1.php). As others have explained, `sum` is then just a convenient mnemonic for `foldl (+) 0 l`.

Presumably its use on the wikipedia page is to illustrate the general principle of summation through tail-recursion. But since the Haskell [Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html) library contains `sum`, which is shorter and more obvious to understand, you should use that in your code.

Here's a [nice discussion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) of Haskell's `fold` functions with simple examples that's well worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see where it says anything about Haskell or `foldl` on that Wikipedia page, but `sum` in Haskell is just a more specific case of `foldl`. It can be implemented like this, for example:

```
sum l = foldl (+) 0 l
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
sum = foldl (+) 0
```

Comment: Aah, now I see it. I had done a search for 'foldl' but the Wikipedia page uses 'fold'.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note is that sum may be lazier than you would want, so consider using foldl'.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the others, there's no difference. However, a sum-call is easier to read than a fold-call, so I'd go for sum if you need summation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. That page is simply saying that `sum` is implemented using `foldl`. Just use `sum` whenever you need to calculate the sum of a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of summation can be extended to non-numeric types: all you need is something equivalent to a (+) operation and a zero value.  In other words, you need a [monoid](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html).  This leads to the Haskell function "mconcat", which returns the sum of a list of values of a monoid type.  The default "mconcat" of course is defined in terms of "mappend" which is the plus operation.